# Combing data frame rows in R based on common values

Tags: r

Given a data frame:

```
    > df <- data.frame( L=c('a','b','b'), t0=c(1,10,20), t1=c(9,19,39))
    > df
      L t0 t1
    1 a  1  9
    2 b 10 19
    3 b 20 39

    I want:
    > df
        L t0 t1
      1 a  1  9
      2 b 10 39
```

The identical values for df$L equals "b" signify that the start (t0) of the first instance of 'b' should be the new 't0' value and the new 't1' value of the last instance of (contiguous) 'b' should be the new 't1' value. In effect, if t0 and t1 are times, then I want to merge the time durations of adjacent rows that have the same value for 'L'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'L', `summarise` to take the `first` value of 't0' and `last` value of 't1' (or `min` and `max`)

```
df %>%
   group_by(L) %>%
    summarise(t0 = first(t0), t1 = last(t1))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  L        t0    t1
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     9
#2 b        10    39
```

---

Based on the OP's comments, if we are also grouping by adjacent similar elements in 'L', use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(L), L) %>%
    summarise(t0 = first(t0), t1 = last(t1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame( L=c('a','b','b','a','b','b'), 
        t0=c(1,10,20,40,60,70), t1=c(9,19,39,49,69,79))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a way to extend this idea if there is more than one "run" of a given label? For example: df <- data.frame( L=c('a','b','b','a','b','b'), t0=c(1,10,20,40,60,70), t1=c(9,19,39,49,69,79)) with repeats of 'a' and 'b' would return four rows: 'a' 1 9, 'b' 10 39, 'a' 40 49, 'b' 60 79.

Comment: @MarkBower  Your comment i not completed.  the example is missing

Comment: @MarkBower  Sorry, earlier didn't see your full comment example. `library(data.table);df %>% group_by(grp = rleid(L), L) %>% summarise(t0 = first(t0), t1 = last(t1))`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help and for your quick responses!

Answer (score 3):

You can `split` by `L` and return the `range`.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df[-1], df[1]), range))
df
#  [,1] [,2]
#a    1    9
#b   10   39

df <- data.frame(L=rownames(df), t0=df[,1], t1=df[,2])
df
#  L t0 t1
#a a  1  9
#b b 10 39
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this be modified to handle "runs" of similar L values?

Comment: @MarkBower When you can group the similar L values to unique classes then use those instead of L.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `aggreate` and `merge`

```
res <- merge(aggregate(t0 ~ L,df,min),aggregate(t1 ~ L,df,max))
```

such that

```
> res
  L t0 t1
1 a  1  9
2 b 10 39
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(t0 = t0[1], t1 = t1[.N]), by = L]

#    L t0 t1
# 1: a  1  9
# 2: b 10 39
```